# WebClient implementation - While executing this piece of code "WebClient.builder().build()" I am getting error

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient, rest, spring-webclient

`WebClient.builder().build()` or `WebClient.create`

I get the below error. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ClientHttpConnector
>
> at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.builder(WebClient.java:154)
> at com.cooperlighting.iot.sample.SampleTest.resend_withSuccessful(SampleTest.java:38)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native  Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
> at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 24 more

Comment: I am trying to make a rest API call using WebClient , I am facing the above mentioned issue. Any suggestion are much appreciated.

Comment: try adding `spring-boot-starter-web`  and try again.

Comment: @BishalGautam - Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it. It's till not working.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml @CodeLearn

Comment: @BishalGautam- sure. But It's too long. is there any other way I can send it to you

Comment: only relevant dependencies of spring would be fine i guess

Comment: @BishalGautam-  spring-boot-starter-web, spring-web,  httpclient, spring-boot-starter-test, spring-boot-starter-webflux. These are the dependencies I added in POM

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

This usually occurs while there is no dependency attached for the given class. Try adding

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Also check for the jar files downloaded and trace it to the class name from the jars.